# How to set up SPIDF channel bits for high sample rate output?

Tags: digital-audio

The original SPIDF standard supported sampling rates only up to 48kHz, but today much higher sample rates are supported. The sample rate was set by controlling [channel status bits](http://www.minidisc.org/spdif_c_channel.html), which also contained other information.

Question: For high sample rate 2-channel output that is used for recording purposes, what should the channel bits be set to? Can I simply set all bits to 0 and have an interface accept the output?

Comment: See `IEC958_AES3_CON_FS_xxx` in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/sound/asoundef.h.

Comment: @CL. Thank you. Do you know recording will work if I leave the bits "non-indicated"? If the interface is configured correctly it should be fine?  Also, what is variable pitch and mask - clock accuracy?

Comment: It is up to the recording device how it works when sampling rate is not indicated. The metadata may be irrelevant, as the receiver must already be locked in and receiving the complete 192kHz stream to find out what the channel status metadata says.

Comment: Basically clock it faster. Whether the status and control bits are active or obeyed is up to individual devices : you may or may not need to pay attention to them. If you don't some devices may work fine, others may refuse.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Do you have knowledge what "mask" - clock accuracy indicates?

Comment: Clock accuracy requirements depend on the equipment you're working with. High quality devices may use crystal oscillators which can only be "pulled" 100-200ppm either side of nominal frequency so I would aim for higher accuracy than that ... better than 50ppm is easy to achieve. The channel bits weren't defined when I was using AES/EBU or SPDIF but I guess there are bits defining the clock accuracy requirement ... just looked and there are ... one of them being 50ppm.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, of course. But if I set it to 3 e.g. "Mask" - clock accuracy, what does this mean? Same for the variable frequency setting, although somewhat self-explanatory...

Comment: Oh from the Linux driver. It means if you compute Channel Status AND Mask, you have extracted the Clock Accuracy bits. That's all.

Comment: It's nice to set the bits according to the latest spec (The @CL. link is great) but be aware that pretty much all gear (except test gear to display channel bits) will ignore all those settings because they are "optional" in the spec and therefore can't be depended on. One of my pet peeves: "optional" parameters in Standards documents.